# customize Kendo.ui.progress to remove spinner

Tags: kendo-grid

Hi i am using progress to disable a grid, i am able to achieve this using

```
 kendo.ui.progress($("#grid"), true);
```

But for my requirement i must not show the spinner image. for that i tried
Method 1

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#grid"), function(){
removeclass("k-loading-image")                ;
return true;
                });
```

Method 2

```
 $('#grid*').prop('disabled', false);
```

Method 3:

```
 $("#grid").append("<div class='k-loading-mask' style='width:100%;height:100%'><span class='k-loading-text'>Loading...</span><div class='k-loading-color'><br\><br\><br\><a href='www.google.com' >LINK</a></div></div>");
```

Any help is much appreciated.Thanks

**EDIT**

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("grdAddrMaster")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.id);
        columns.Bound(m => m.name);

    })
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Pageable()   
    .Selectable()
   .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                            .Extra(false)
                            .Operators(operators => operators
                            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                            .StartsWith("Starts With"))
                            .ForNumber(num => num.ToString()
                            .StartsWith("Starts With"))
                            ))

    .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
                                        .Model(model =>
                                        {
                                            model.Id(m => m.id);
                                        })
                                        .PageSize(10)
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadData", "Home"))))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to remove the loading image then you just need to create a css class to override the existing background image of the loading image class as below:

```
.k-loading-image {
   //background-image: url('Default/loading-image.gif'); // Existing code in the css (kendo.default.min.css)
  background-image: url('your logo') !important; // path to your logo which you wish to show
}
```

---

**Edit:**
**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/hoviv/1/edit)**

You will need to add the below line to disable the Loading image at run time:

```
  kendo.ui.progress($("#grdAddrMaster"), true);
  $("#grdAddrMaster").find(".k-loading-image").css("background-image", "url('') !important");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I applied the same in my script file and am still getting the loader image in my grid. am i missing  some thing. My Grid ID "grdAddrMaster"                                                     used in the below code kendo.ui.progress($("#grdAddrMaster"), true)
        $("<div class='k-loading-image'>").css({
            "background-image": "url('NA') !important"
        }).appendTo($("#grdAddrMaster"));

Comment: YOU don't need to add the css at run time, you can just add the css to your styling of the page and it will do the rest of the work, see my edit with working example.

Comment: My requirement is like while loading the grid i have the usual mask with spinner and is fine. On row select i am showing the details below in another view. I have a button edit and on click of edit i have to disable the grid with kendo.ui.progress without the spinner/loading image untill the user finishes the edit and clicks save/cancel

Comment: Please see my edit, I have just changed a bit of code as per what you had wrote.

Comment: This is working partially as rowSelect and sort is still available for the user. PLease see my grid code in question. edit